# Craft 3 Plugin: Saved image asset has no width / height

Tags: plugin-development, image, twigextension

In my Craft 3 Plugin I am saving an image (YouTube poster) to an asset volume like this:

```
$asset = new Asset();
$asset->title = $url;
$asset->tempFilePath = $tmpPath; // temp path for image in /storage/runtime/temp/
$asset->volumeId = $volumeId; // ID of my Asset Volume
$asset->filename = $filename; // filename like youtube_<youTubeKey>.jpg
$asset->newFolderId = $folder->id; // root folder id of the volume
$asset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
$asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);
clearstatcache();
list ($w, $h) = Image::imageSize($tmpPath);
$asset->setWidth($w);
$asset->setHeight($h);
$result = Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);
```

The image saved does not have width or height (so it's there while saving), so if I later output its width like this in TWIG: `{{ dump(img.width) }}` it will be `NULL`.

Any hints what I need to call so that craft persists the image width / height?

Comment: You shouldn't set the width/height yourself, but that shouldn't matter. Is there a chance that you're using multisite and this is earlier than Craft 3.0.0-beta23? If so, you should update Craft. If not, you should get in touch via support@craftcms.com

Comment: Hi Andris, yes multisite & beta 22. I filed the bug that you fixed. But I can't update at the moment, 23 has a severe bug for me. ok, then I will wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andris Sevcenko pointed out, the problem is Craft 3 Beta 22 and a Multisite Configuration. Fixed in Beta 23.